# SAP HANA - Change password SQL

Tags: sql, hana, change-password

How do I change my password in SAP HANA via SQL.
(or other users if I am an Administrator)

I did view the HANA Dokumentation : [ALTER USER Statement](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/20d3459f75191014a7bbeb670bad8850.html#loio20d3459f75191014a7bbeb670bad8850__sql_alter_user_1sql_alter_user_password_val_option)

So I tried `ALTER USER <user_name> PASSWORD '<new_password>'` with no success.

Answer (score 12):

Use double quotes : `ALTER USER <user_name> PASSWORD "<new_password>"`

(Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the provided Link).

Comment: the doc mentions no quotes at all

Comment: The command actually is ALTER USER <user_name> PASSWORD <new_password>. The double quotes are only required for passwords with special characters.

Comment: @LarsBr.Thx I updated Q&A. Feel free to edit the question / answer next time